# Javascript mobile redirect, page keeps refreshing

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

I'm trying to redirect all my site mobile traffic to one page.

so I added redirect code in header.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<!-- if (screen.width <= 699)

{ document.location = "/page/mobile/";

}

//-->

</script>
```

The problem is that after redirecting script continuous executing because header is the same on the whole site. so it's refreshing the page over and over again.

I want javascript to check for the /page/mobile/ in url and if it's there, do not execute redirect.

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this.

```
if ( window.location.pathname !== "/page/mobile"){
   window.location.href = "https://[your-host-name]/page/mobile";
}
```

So you can use `window.location.pathname` to access your path after host (and port)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Answer (score 0):

check window location in your if condition

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("/mobile/")>-1){
  console.log("You are on mobile page")
}
```